# Error when Launching App with Frameworks - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When compiling and installing my app on a simulator/my device using the latest version of Google Ad Mobile SDK (7.68.0) I receive this error...

```
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9B9B907-B164-48B3-B71D-FEFF3A42B95C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8US3se/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9B9B907-B164-48B3-B71D-FEFF3A42B95C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8US3se/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
--
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9B9B907-B164-48B3-B71D-FEFF3A42B95C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8US3se/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about Info.plist: Couldn't stat /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9B9B907-B164-48B3-B71D-FEFF3A42B95C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8US3se/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 35
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 131;
}
--
System Information
macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.2 (17535) (Build 12B45b)
Timestamp: 2020-11-26T18:13:21-05:00
```

When trying to install it using my device I get this error...

```
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013037e99f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001303bd164 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d34f993 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001303bcea5 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000013022d7bc __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d47e2ae __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d47fed0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201725dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201737c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201795fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2017a0cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20183c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2031b499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2031a467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.2 (17535) (Build 12B45b)
Timestamp: 2020-11-26T17:02:40-05:00
```

If anyone has any solutions I would be very grateful.

Comment: Read the error message.  It says exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @ElTomato I did and I also searched the path for the info.plist and it is present and looks error-free which is the issue

Comment: Okay.  Sorry about that, then.

Comment: Does this file exist: `/Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A9B9B907-B164-48B3-B71D-FEFF3A42B95C/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.8US3se/extracted/AppName.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist`?  If not, may be a build problem, like failure to add this to a 'copy files' build phase.If so, I don't have any guesses.

Comment: @mr.fixit no it does not exist when searching for it in finder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it was related to my private pods.
How I solved this:

1. Delete the old app;
2. Close the XCode;
3. `pod deintegrate`;
4. `pod install --clean-install`;
5. Open XCode, clean and clean build folder;
6. Run the project.

I using XCode 12.2 with MacOS 10.15.6.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. after updating admob sdk i had issues with installing. this worked